# How merge a Data Frame and a Spatial Polygon Data Frame?

Tags: r, merge, spatial

I have a Data Frame named `mean_HouseValue` and a Spatial Polygon Data Frame named `California_shp` as follow:

```
head(mean_HouseValue)
    Group.1         x
1   Alameda 208747.39
2    Alpine 118700.00
3    Amador 117146.43
4     Butte  89611.54
5 Calaveras 107893.75
6    Colusa  77731.25

head(California_shp)
       NAME
1   Alameda
2    Alpine
3    Amador
4     Butte
5 Calaveras
6    Colusa
```

How can I merge `mean_HouseValue` and `California_shp` to have a spatial data?

Comment: You can use geom_join from library(tigris)

Comment: `left_join()` from `dplyr` package should do.

Answer (score 0):

If your polygons are class `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` (or some other `sp` class), you can use `sp::merge`.

```
library(sp)

merged <- merge(California_shp, mean_HouseValue, by.x = 'NAME', by.y = 'Group.1')
```